# How to select a text node child of the span node

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

My page has multiple "Active users" with different "tag number". Here, I want select Active user, tag 00015339, but unable to write a correct xpath for it. I want to write an xpath, which can retrieve all Active user irrespective of tag number.

Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <h3 class="action action-success inline-block" title="Edit user">
        <span>User Latha9</span>
        <i class="icon icon-edit m-l-sm" title="Edit user"/>
    </h3>
</div>
<span>Active user, tag 00015339</span>
```

Comment: I don't see any tag or attribute with 00015339 in your html...

Comment: I think you should actually add an attribute like `data-tag="00015339"` and then query it. Querying the DOM through the text of each node will be costly.

Comment: Those are the values(text) retrieved dynamically... I want to count number of Users who has the attribute <span> Active user, tag xxxxx</span> with an xpath.

Comment: Try `//span[starts-with(., 'Active user')` BTW, this is *not* an attribute of a node, but a text node child of the `span` node.

Comment: I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: //span[starts-with(., 'Active user')] is working.

Comment: If you control the markup you could add a class or other attribute to the span and save yourself a lot of hassle :-)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Markus

```
//span[starts-with(., 'Active user')]
```

This xpath works for my scenario.